# CELL("contents", ) in EXCEL

Tags: excel

I have a cell (A1) in sheet 4 that is containing the following formula:

```
=CELL("contents",Sheet1!B61)
```

However, I want to find the content of the result. When I try to formulate it

```
=CELL("contents",A1)
```

The result is the same.

What I want to find is the content of =CELL("contents",Sheet1!B61). Is it possible to enclose it with a cell function twice? I've been trying to formulate it but there is always an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot imagine a scenario in which it would be necessary to generate text strings representing cell addresses and then reference these in formulas. However:

`=CELL("contents",INDIRECT(Sheet1!B61))`

is what you require.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

=CELL("contents",Sheet1!B61) is the same as =Sheet1!B61.

I think you are looking for INDIRECT which will translate a cell address given as text to the value contained in the cell.

=INDIRECT(Sheet1!B61)

Answer (score -2):

Idk, try a nested CELL(CELL=(...)) not sure if it will work but...

Also, can you clarify exactly what you want?  When you have

```
=CELL("contents",Sheet1!B61)
```

I assume the result is a number or text or whatever

Then you say, "I want to find the content of the result".  What do you mean here? You want the cell (A1) in sheet 4 to display something other than the result of the formula above?  If so, just change the formula.  I think I'm a little lost here...

Comment: '=CELL("contents",Sheet1!B61)' -- The result will be the address of the selected cell in sheet 1 (B61 is the holder of that address). 

For example, in B61 I have a data of $B$60. I want to show the contents of $B$60. However the data in B61 varies (depending on the address of the selected cell)